# Laravel eager loading - one to many relation

Tags: laravel, one-to-many, eager-loading, has-many

laravel dev.

I have three **tables** let's say ***A, B, C***

```
A
-----------
-id
-main_location_id // **main location entry = 1**

B
-----------
-id
-a_id
-allocated_qty

C
-----------    
-id
-a_id
-location_id // **main location enrty + other locations enrty- 1,2,3**
-total_qty
-aval_qty
```

**Relation:**

> **table *A* has many of *B***
>
> **table *A* also has many of *C***

**Query:**

```
A::with(['B'])
->with(['C']) // here I got all location object from C tables, but I only want main_location_id = location_id data object + its qty
->where('a.id', 1)
->first();
```

I don't understand how will I get **location_id, total_qty, aval_qty** from table **C** through table **A**

which has **c.location_id = a.main_location_id**

Even I don't know if I'm doing right?

is this possible?

please help me with this

Many thanks!

Comment: You have to query tabler C and filter it with a query, which is referring to A. Example `$c = C::with(['A' => fn ($query) => $query->where('id', '=', 'a_id')])->get();` See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how you define that relation. if you define a relation in your code like so:

```php
// models/A.php
public function c() {
    return $this->hasMany(C::class);
}
```

it will use the primary key of `A` by default, which is `id`, so that becomes `a_id` when Laravel prefixes the table name. This then becomes an array of many `C`s that belong to `A` through `A.id = C.a_id`. You have to pass more parameters to `hasMany` to define your own keys.

However, the relation you need seems to be a `hasOne` relation: your `A` only has one `C` through `A.main_location_id = C.location_id`. So you could define a `hasOne` with manual keys like so:

```php
// models/A.php
public function c() {
    return $this->hasOne(C::class, 'location_id', 'main_location_id');
}
```

If that is the wrong key, you have to pass extra parameters to the `hasOne()` relation definition.

If you need both of those relations, simply rename the function (use plural and singular form if you have proper table names), and you can for instance use `A::query()->with(['c', 'singleC'])`

Comment: I have tried your sugeestion
```// models/A.php
public function c() {
    return $this->hasOne(C::class, 'location_id', 'main_location_id');
}```

but it gives me first occurrence records from the C table which is wrong I need the same ```a_id+ mfg_location_id```  records from the C table